# Grails RabbitMQ plugin how to delete everything queued

Tags: grails, rabbitmq

I am developing and using RabbitMQ and for now it is not helpful to have jobs persisted when i turn off my app.  Is there a line I can drop in my bootstrap to delete everything or a config option to make Rabbit essentially "create-drop"?

Should probably add I am using an unmodified version of whatever the current RabbitMQ plugin is.

Comment: I'm not well versed in Grails or Spring so can't offer a definitive answer so I'll just leave as a comment the notion that Rabbit supports self-deleting queues. When declared as such, a queue will delete itself once all consumer connections to it have gone.